UriBuilder unexpected behavior, or is it?
The documentation says

The port number defines the protocol port for contacting the host referenced in the URI. If a port is not specified as part of the URI, the Port property returns the value of -1 to indicate that the default port value for the protocol scheme will be used to connect to the host. If the Port property is set to a value of -1, this indicates that the default port value for the protocol scheme will be used to connect to the host.

(I don't care c# or VB, current code happened to be VB)
Public Sub Main()
        
    dim logonLink as string = "https://website/application/login.aspx"
    Console.WriteLine("RETURN: {0}", logonLink)

    Dim uriBuilder As New UriBuilder(logonLink)     
    Console.WriteLine("HOST: {0}", uriBuilder.Host)
    Console.WriteLine("PORT: {0}", uriBuilder.Port)

End Sub

However, when this code runs, if the link contains http - port number shows 80, and https - 443. While I expect -1.
This is in FW4.7.2
Do I miss something?
PS: Uri does same thing but at least is has IsDefaultPort
Dim uri As Uri = nothing
Uri.TryCreate(logonLink, UriKind.Absolute, uri)
Console.WriteLine("URI PORT: {0}", uri.Port)
Console.WriteLine("URI PORT def: {0}", uri.IsDefaultPort)


The UriBuilder string constructor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder.-ctor?view=net-9.0#system-uribuilder-ctor(system-string) uses Uri to parse the string, then copies Uri.Port. Which will return the default port for the specified protocol https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.port?view=net-9.0#remarks. Using any of the other constructors will leave the port uninitialised.

@JeremyLakeman This is on Uri doc.. But not on builder. Will look more

You are doing more than just reading the .Port property. First you are calling the constructor;

This constructor initializes a new instance of the UriBuilder class with the Fragment, Host, Path, Port, Query, Scheme, and Uri properties set as specified in uri.

Which references Uri.Port;

The port number defines the protocol port used for contacting the server referenced in the URI. If a port is not specified as part of the URI, the Port property returns the default value for the protocol. If there is no default port number, this property returns -1.

So if you use this constructor, the port number will be the default port of any well known protocol. If you use any other constructor, the port number should be left as the default -1.
Reading the current source code for UriBuilder, I found this surprise;
        public Uri Uri
        {
            get
            {
                if (_changed)
                {
                    _uri = new Uri(ToString());
                    SetFieldsFromUri();
                    _changed = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Assert(_uri is not null);
                }
                return _uri;
            }
        }

Merely reading the .Uri can change the value of all other properties. So if you leave the .Port number alone, but change anything else. Then read the .Uri property. The .Port number will also change to the default port.

"Merely reading the .Uri can change the value of all other properties" is a rather unexpected design. I wonder why they did that.

It looks like UriBuilder dates back to .net 1. If I tried to propose a class like this now, I suspect it would be rejected.

Am I missing something here? UriBuilder.Port is defined as public int Port { get; set; }. I have not reflected this code yet.. Are you saying that in the getter/setter UriBuilder.Port references Uri.Port? interesting...  I don't even see UriBuilder(string) constructor in that code ^^

@T.S. - you seem to have skipped over/ignored the first part of the answer - you're constructing your UriBuilder via a Uri. The constructor says it copies the Port property from the Uri. The bit about accessing the Uri property is interesting but is more of an aside than the part you should be focussing on.

It seems coming from UriParser, which has parser for all schemas private static readonly Dictionary<string, UriParser> m_Table = new Dictionary<string, UriParser>(25); And one for https comes like UriParser.HttpsUri = (UriParser) new UriParser.BuiltInUriParser("https", 443, UriParser.HttpUri.m_Flags); Basically, microsoft documentation is not clear to say the least

I accept your answer on the premise that it pointed me into discovery of things and that Microsoft documentation becoming worse with time

That's hardly fair in this case. It does describe the behaviour of UrlBuilder in isolation. It's ancient and was poorly designed in the first place. Changing that behaviour would risk breaking a lot of software. The documentation here hasn't gotten any worse.
